# android returning string from php without json

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to return a string from my php file to my android application. The php file is not in json form. jsonobject just returns error `07-28 20:10:56.538: W/System.err(2936): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` I have also tried SAXParser, but i understand that that is for xml files only. When I use a `StringBuilder` like such

```
public static String iStream_to_String(InputStream is1) {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1), 8192);
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String longitudecord = "";
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");

        }
//          rd.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
    return contentOfMyInputStream;
}
```

I get a response much like this one `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
 the response That I want to get is a simple string returning a given error file. is there any possible way to do such a simple task without json?

also i want to add the file type of the php is `application/x-httpd-php` if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just calling the php wrong:/